# Can "central" be an adjective for 'country' or not?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

In the passage below, is "central" an adjective for 'country', or not?

> There was discovered a peddler's tin box as well as the bones, and
> this box is now preserved at Lilydale, **the central country
> head-quarters** of the American Spiritualists, to which also the old Hydesville house has been transported.
>
> [Source](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html)

Does "the central country head-quarters" mean 'the central headquarters of America'?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options hear. First let us clarify that Lilydale seems to be the main headquarters of the spiritualist churches in the USA according to its [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lily_Dale%2C_New_York).

> the central country head-quarters

This could mean that both central and country are modifying head-quarters so it means the central head-quarters which are located in the country. From the Wikipedia article that statement would appear to be true. Alternatively it could mean that it was the national head-quarters, the most important one in the country. That uses central in the sense of important. From the Wikipedia article that statement too appears to be true.

As @Foogood mentions in their answer it seems unlikely to mean head-quarters for the central region of the USA as it would be more natural to replace country with its name if that was intended.

Answer (score 0):

This use is actually a little ambiguous.  "the central country head-quarters" could mean either "the central headquarters of the country" or it could mean "the headquarters of the central country".

However, in English, it is more common when talking about a country to use the name of the country itself, rather than just saying "the country", so if it was talking about the "central headquarters" for the whole country I would expect it to say something more like "central American head-quarters" or "central U.S. head-quarters" instead, so my guess in this case is that it may actually mean that it's the headquarters for the "central country", that is the middle part of the U.S.

On the other hand, I note that the source was written some time ago (by Arthur Conan Doyle), so the conventions may have been different back then, I'm not sure.  In which case, my guess may be entirely wrong.

So it really isn't entirely clear, and the only way to be sure is probably to find some more information somewhere about what sort of "head-quarters" Lilydale actually was to the American Spiritualists at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that is *not* good English.

First, what would the “country headquarters” be?  I can think of no sensible interpretation except the headquarters for the entire organization in the country, as distinct from a regional headquarters or even a world headquarters.

That should be called the “national headquarters”.  That is just the way we say that in English.

Let’s assume that is the meaning, though; what is the “central national headquarters”?  “Central” can mean literally in the geometric or geometric central, like “the central time zone” (which covers roughly the center of North America) or “Central America” (which is between North and South America).

It can also mean “very important, key”, like the “central nervous system”, which is not located in the center of your physical body, but is certainly the most important.

I don’t see how either of those meanings really make sense in the context of a national headquarters.  By definition, there is only one national headquarters in a given country; why would you qualify it as “central” in any sense of the word?

Comment: You need to remember that the source is from Arthur Conan Doyle, who wrote in the late 1800s until the late 1920s. You know, the guy who wrote the Sherlock Holmes novels. Also he was Scottish, not American. Language and usage have changed considerably over the intervening years (even here in Scotland where I live). What may seem odd to us, may have not been back then.  It's a bit like looking at Shakespeare's works and concluding they are bad English based on modern usage.

Comment: @BillyKerr — I have read a lot of Doyle (none of his Spiritualism nonsense) and though his diction sometimes feels a bit archaic, this passage, I think is just bad.  “Country headquarters” might have been the Scottish way to say “national headquarters” (especially given the UK propensity to refer to political components like Scotland and Wales as “countries”), but the adjective “central” does not seem to have any meaning at all here.